# Sprites move between cgpoints? in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

How to place a sprites in the CGPoint -

- while adding new sprite it should placed  in CGPoint?
- while move from one CGPoint to the Another CGPoint?

in cocos2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `setPosition:(CGPoint) point` on all CCNodes. You can do this at any time, including creation.

Comment: Multiple CGPoints? What are these points? Where are you storing them?

Comment: Its a boardtype game so there are 20-50 points while init is called placing the sprites one by one and make it stable until condition satisfy?